# Using ruby array inside JS.erb to plot locations on a map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to use JS to plot points on a map, using google's API. I can get it to use values if I input them manually, but I need to be able to add them via Ruby.

Here's the code that works:

```
   function initMap() {

    var mapv2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapv2'), {
    zoom: 3,
   center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
   });

   var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

   var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(mapv2, markers,
  {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
  var locations = [
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
  {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
  {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
  {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
  {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
  {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
];
```

The bit that I'm trying to change is locations. Here's what I've come up with but it's not working:

**Update**

```
  function initMap() {

  var mapv2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapv2'), {
zoom: 3,
  center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
  });

  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  var markers = locations.each(function(location, i) {
return new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
  });

   var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(mapv2, markers,
  {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
  var locations = '<%= @array %>';
```

@latitude and longitude return an array of co-ordinates, in rails. Hopefully that makes sense. If you need anything else, please let me know! Any pointing in the right direction, or constructive criticism is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
So in my controller I have:

```
  def index
    @places = Place.all
    @longitude = @places.pluck(:longitude)
    @latitude = @places.pluck(:latitude)
  end
```

Comment: `var latitude = "<%= @latitude %>";` You are trying to put the `to_s` of a ruby array into another string in js, then put that string into a javascript object with no key. I know you mentioned you are new to development. But I would suggest you learn a little more.

Comment: Can you show us how are `@latitude` and `@longitude` are set in the controller?

Comment: If `@latitude` is / returns an array, it should be called `@latitudes` (plural). And the corresponding variable in JavaScript should be `var latitutes`. Same for `longitude`. With that changes in place, it becomes quite obvious, that `locations = [{latitudes, longitudes}]` doesn't make much sense. JavaScript cannot automatically turn a bunch of numbers into objects with `lat` and `lng` properties. You have to write that code.

Comment: @DickieBoy Thanks for your super unhelpful, nonconstructive and demeaning response. I asked a question and clearly said, pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Suggesting I "learn a little more"  without any links or direction as to what I should be learning is, well, the worst answer to a question I've ever seen. I'm proud to where I've got to coding in the last 6 months, all of that on rails, not JS. I barely ask any questions and I'm self-taught. Maybe next time you reply to a question, you'll get off your high-horse and do what this sites made for, helping people.

Comment: @JackStovell I think you took that the wrong way. It was not meant to be any of those things. My comment was meant to guide you into the correct direction and allow you to work the answer out for yourself.

Comment: @DickieBoy apologies, that's not how it came across to me, but thank you for clearing that and your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by combining answers from @dickieboy & @pavan and then adding in gsub to remove the quotes. I also moved all the code inside a script on my html page. Here's the complete code:

**Places Controller**

```
def index
 @places = Place.all
 @array = []
 @places.each do |place|
   @array.push({
    lat: place.latitude,
    lng: place.longitude
  })
 end
end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div id="mapv2"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function initMap() {
   var locations = <%= @array.to_json.gsub(/\s|"|'/,'') %>;
   var mapv2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapv2'), {
zoom: 3,
center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
   });

   var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

   var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
return new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  label: labels[i % labels.length]
});
});

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(mapv2, markers,
  {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}  

 </script>


 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**End result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> @latitude and longitude return an array of co-ordinates

Well in that case it not gonna work, since you need **array of hashes** with `lat` and `lng` as keys.

You should extract the *latitude* and *longitude* for each *location*, construct a hash with `lat`, `lng` keys and push those to an array.

Since there isn't much information provided, I'm going to assume and provide a sample example

**Example:**

```
@locations = #location objects with lat and lng coordinates
@array = []
@locations.each do |location|
  @array.push({
    lat: location.latitude,
    lng: location.longitude
  })
end
```

And then in `js.erb`, just do

```
var locations = '<%= @array %>';
```

**Update:**

With your updated code, the above example should like below

```
@places = Place.all
@array = []
@places.each do |place|
  @array.push({
    lat: place.latitude,
    lng: place.longitude
  })
end
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, thanks for this. I can see the code in my controller works great now thanks to your answer. However, the locations won't load on my map. I opened the console and it says "Uncaught TypeError: locations.map is not a function". Any ideas on that one? Thanks again.

Comment: line 10 - var markers = locations.map(function(location, i){

Comment: @JackStovell Try `each` instead of `map`

Comment: I get the same problem with that: locations.each is not a function. I'll update the code above with what I have

Comment: @JackStovell Try putting `var locations = '<%= @array %>';` before `var markers = locations.each(function(location, i) {`

Comment: Hi @Pavan, no luck! Could it be to do with the output of the array? As the output comes out as  {:lat=>-31.563910, :lng=>147.154312} in html. Where previously the code was input as {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312}.

Comment: @JackStovell Can you print the value of `@array` I want to see how the structure is.

Comment: [{:lat=>51.5073509, :lng=>-0.1277583}, {:lat=>40.741895, :lng=>-73.989308}, {:lat=>51.3932, :lng=>-0.1996}, {:lat=>53.4807593, :lng=>-2.2426305}, {:lat=>51.5505034, :lng=>0.6193284}] - that's from the view.

Comment: @JackStovell I wonder whether you have Jquery running in your app?

Comment: I do yes & turbolinks

Comment: @JackStovell Hmm. ok. Seems like it is something to do with looping. I will get back to you on this later.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
places = Place.all

@coordinates = places.map{|place| {lat: place.latitude, lng: place.longitude}}
```

in your view:

```
var locations = <%= @coordinates.to_json %>;
```